# GKE Nginx Ingress - Setting host causes 400 No required SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx ingress in GKE 1.16.13-gke.401.

**My Configuration**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "development/client-cert-api-ingress"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Automatically redirect http to https
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # Use regex in paths
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # For notifications we add the proxy headers
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
      secretName: api-tls-certificate
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: v2-api-frontend
          servicePort: 443
```

Nginx controller config:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingressnginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

**The Problem**

Calling `curl -k --cert my-cert.pem --key my-cert.key https://MY_IP/ --header "Host: example.com"` doesn't work when `rules.host` is specified.

If I am specifing `rules.host` server responding with

> 400 Bad Request
> No required SSL certificate was sent

If I am not specifying `rules.host` the curl works fine.

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1:**

It seems like the client certificate I issued which is self-signed caused the problem.

Created using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# USE: ./build-client-cert.sh <CERTNAME> <EXPR_DAYS>

# How to generate client certificate
# based on https://www.makethenmakeinstall.com/2014/05/ssl-client-authentication-step-by-step/

openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.req
openssl x509 -req -in client.req -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -set_serial 101 -extensions client -days $2 -outform PEM -out client.cer
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey client.key -in client.cer -out $1.p12
rm client.key client.cer client.req
```

When using cloudflare the server responds correctly, Only when using my certificate through curl this happens.

**Edit 2**

Created the CA using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309

openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
```

Comment: Whats the output if you ignore ssl check? `curl -IL "Host: example.com" https://MY_IP -k` ?

Comment: HTTP/2 400
date: Tue, 20 Oct 2020 11:54:26 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 230

Comment: Interesting part is that you said: if you don't specifying the `rules.host` everything works fine. So the certificate was issued with the `example.com`? It is a self-sign? PLease give more details.

Comment: It is self-signed. It seems like the client certificate I Issued causes this problem. Using cloudflare client certificate works fine. I will add the code for creating the problematic client cert. @KoopaKiller

Comment: Coul you please show hwo did you create the secrets for the certificates and CA?